Integrating $\int_0^1\frac{x-x^2}{\ln x}dx$ using gamma function
$$\int_0^1\frac{x-x^2}{\ln x}dx$$
How to solve this integral without using exponential integral Ei? like using the definition of the gamma function.
I tried to solve it using gamma function, beta function and getting Laplace transform from it but had no result.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Here is a hint: $$\frac{x^2-x}{\log x}=\int_{1}^{2}x^s,\mathrm{d}s$$ Also, as pointed out by other users, your question does not meet the quality standards enforced in this community. Please consider improving your question by, for example, providing contexts, your own thoughts, and/or your attempts.

Hint: the substitution $u=-\ln x$ gives a Frullani integral, but like @SangchuiLee's suggestion it doesn't use the Gamma function, unless we replace a $u^{-1}$ factor in the integrand with $u^{\epsilon-1}$ then take $\epsilon\to0^+$.

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^a-x^b}{\ln x}dx\overset{x=e^{-t}}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-(b+1)t}-e^{-(a+1)t}}tdt\overset{IBP}{=}$$$$(b+1)\int_0^\infty \ln t ,e^{-(b+1)t}dt-(a+1)\int_0^\infty \ln t ,e^{-(a+1)t}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(\ln\frac x{1+b}-\ln\frac x{1+a}\right)dx$$
$$=\ln\frac{1+a}{1+b}$$

In general,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^a-x^b}{\ln x} d x&=\int_0^1 \int_b^a x^y d y d x 
\\& =\int_b^a \int_0^1 x^y d x d y \\
& =\int_b^a\left[\frac{x^{y+1}}{y+1}\right]_0^1 d y \\
& =\int_b^a \frac{1}{y+1} d y \\
& =[\ln (y+1)]_b^a \\
& =\ln \left(\frac{a+1}{b+1}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Why not use Differentiation Under the Integral Sign?
First, we define the following:
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x-x^a}{\ln{x}}}dx$$
Next, we take the derivative of both sides with respect to a:
$$I'(a)=\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x-x^a}{\ln{x}}}=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\partial}{\partial{a}}{\left(\frac{x-x^a}{\ln{x}}\right)}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}{{\frac{0-x^{a}\ln{x}}{\ln{x}}}}dx=-\int_{0}^{1}{x^a}dx$$
Evaluating the integral on the right side:
$$I'(a)=-\frac{1}{a+1}$$
Now, integrate both sides with respect to $a$:
$$I(a)=-\ln{(a+1)}+C$$
For the arbitrary constant, C, let $a=1$ to find its value:
$$I(1)=-\ln{2}+C\Rightarrow C=0+\ln{2}=\ln{2}$$
This is because, at $a=1$:
$$I(1)=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x-x^1}{\ln{x}}}dx=0$$
Therefore,
$$I(a)=-\ln{(a+1)}+\ln{2}=-\ln{\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}$$
So, at $a=2$:
$$I(2)=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x-x^2}{\ln{x}}}dx=-\ln{\left(\frac{2+1}{2}\right)}=\boxed{-\ln{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}}$$

$$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x-x^2}{\log(x)} \, dx=-\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
which follow from
$$f(x)=\int \frac{x-x^2}{\log(x)} \, dx\\=\text{Ei}(2 \log(x))-\text{Ei}(3 \log(x))=\Gamma(0,-3 \log(x))-\Gamma(0,-2 \log(x)),\quad 0\le x<1$$
where
$f(0)=0$ and $\underset{x\to 1^-}{\text{lim}} f(x)=-\log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$.
